# Programming the GITLAB server - possible?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'd love to automate some of the per-project features of my GITLAB repo. For instance I'd like to connect it to Jenkins. Is there a way I can do this using a GIT command or perhaps issuing some kind of call to the GITLAB server. Is any of this possible or am I left having to do it through the menu system (which is all the documentation I can find)?

I've done it through the menu system, but that is too manual.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my question. I found the "programming" information for talking directly to the Gitlab server. It can be found here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).